# Does require in node js, updates value at run time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have something like

```
var some_data=require('../objects/some_data.json');

function(){
  //something here to change data of some_data.json - fs.write 
  //vl this affect value of some_data at this point ?
}
```

Does require keep active reference to files OR just reads it once while requiring ?

If it keeps active ref , how can i retain old value of some_data

Comment: it doesnt affect some_data , figured it out, btw thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It loads the file, how it is on start. It doesn't take any changes you are doing to the json file.

For example, run this

```
var b = require("./a.json");
for (var i = 0; i< 1000000; i++) {
    console.log(b.a);
}
```

with this json a.json

```
{
  "a": "b"
}
```

And change the value whilst in the loop - or delete the file. It will still work.

Comment: but its contradictory to @mikemaccana answer, according to u some_data wont change , but from his answer i guess it vl

Comment: No, it's not... @aishwatsingh

Comment: @aishwatsingh Changes to the file will have no effect. Changes to the same required object will have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

It keeps an active reference. Ie, objects loaded via require are singletons.

From https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders :

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded.
>
> Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be executed multiple times.

Say you have a file called `deleteme.json` with the following contents:

```
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

Let's try requiring it, changing it, then requiring it again:

```
var data = require('./deleteme.json')
data.key = "newvalue"
data = require('./deleteme.json')
console.log(data)
```

You'll see it logs `newvalue` - since the object isn't reloaded, an the original stays in memory.

Since you asked about deleting the file: you can delete the file, since it's in memory. Deleting the file will only stop when you start node again and load the module for the first time.

Comment: i am directly loading a json object in that some_data , is it good approach then , also can u say abt EDIT part ?

Comment: @aishwatsingh I've added some test code showing you editing the object to illustrate this.